# How to pass command line arguments to the platform main routine using vscode launch.json?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

When developing a flutter app (desktop in this case), I wish to pass a few command line arguments to the platform c++ main that is created with the project template for windows.

Although I'm targeting desktop, I guess the `launch.json` configuration should be the same for all targets.

Here is my failed attempt with `launch.json`:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "wideview",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "debug",
            "args-to-main": [
                "--wait-for-debugger-attach" // HOW???
            ],
            
        },

    ]
}
```

So how can I achieve this?

Also, an example of how to pass command line args to the dart application would be nice.

Comment: so you're not looking for the `args` property, which passes arguments to the Dart script?

Comment: @starball no, the embedder / platform loads much earlier than the dart code. I need a way to pass arguments to the embedder.